# How to Hide multiple dynamic Columns in JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here I have set one button, which is toggle button. If I click that button Part of my fields should be hide. If I hit again, Hidden field should be show. This is my scenario.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
 <!-- My toggle button code is here -->
 <td  align="center">
    <input type="button" id="viewbutton"  style="width:80px;" class="button" onclick = "hide()" value="View More"/> 
  </td>

<!-- My headers of the table which are all hide while I hit the above button-->
<tr>
  <th width='120' scope='col' id='remarks'><div align="left">Remarks</div></th>
  <th width='66' scope='col' id='lan' ><div align="left">LAN Mac Address</div></th>
  <th width='70' scope='col' id='wifi' ><div align="left">Wifi Mac Address</div></th>
  <th width='65' scope='col' id='scrapped' ><div align="center">Scrapped date</div></th>

</tr>
<?php  PopulateSystemAsset_byLocation($location_posted,$asset_type_posted,$employees_posted,"LIST") ?>
```

Dynamic Fields are:

```
function populateSystemAsset_byLocation($locations,$asset_types,$employees,$check)
 {

  while($fetchedquery = mysql_fetch_array($selectquery))

    //Retrieve all field from Database and assigned to variable (assume)

    echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td align='left'>$asset_type</td>
         <td align='left'>$asset_description</td>";

        echo "<td align='left' id='remarks_Ans'>$Remarks</td>"; 

        if($LAN_addr == '' || $LAN_addr == 'NULL' ) 
        { 
            echo "<td align='center' id='lan_Ans'></td>";
        }
       else
       {
            echo "<td align='center' id='lan_Ans'>$LAN_addr</td>";  //Formatted Date
       }

        if($Wifi_addr == '' || $Wifi_addr == 'NULL' ) 
        { 
            echo "<td align='center' id='wifi_Ans'></td>";
        }
       else
       {
            echo "<td align='center' id='wifi_Ans'>$Wifi_addr</td>";  //Formatted Date
       }


       if($asset_scrapped_date == '' || $asset_scrapped_date == '0000-00-00') 
        { 
            echo "<td align='center' id='scrapped_Ans'></td>";
        }
       else
        {
            echo "<td align='center' id='scrapped_Ans'>$ScrappedDateFormatted</td>";  //Formatted Date
        }
      echo "</tr>";

 }//while
}//function
```

My Javascript code :

```
   //Initially I Hide my fiels while page loads 

<script type="application/javascript">
  var flag = 0;

  function hide()
   {
    if(flag == 0)
    {
    document.getElementById("viewbutton").value = "View Less";
    document.getElementById("remarks").style.display = "table-cell";
    document.getElementById("lan").style.display = "table-cell";
    document.getElementById("wifi").style.display = "table-cell";
    document.getElementById("scrapped").style.display = "table-cell";
    document.getElementById("remarks_Ans").style.display = "table-cell";
    document.getElementById("lan_Ans").style.display = "table-cell";
    document.getElementById("wifi_Ans").style.display = "table-cell";
    document.getElementById("scrapped_Ans").style.display = "table-cell";
    flag = 1;
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById("viewbutton").value = "View More";
    document.getElementById("remarks").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("lan").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("wifi").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("scrapped").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("remarks_Ans").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("lan_Ans").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("wifi_Ans").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("scrapped_Ans").style.display = "none";
    flag = 0;
    }
  }
</script>
```

My Problem:
But my problem is only hide headers and first row fields. Remaining rows does not hide. I don't know why second and future row's columns are not hide.

Please anyone help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Give class to every tr then hide using that. You can not use same id multiple time.

Comment: ya thanks sunil. I have changed my id as Class. And also changed js code as document.getElementsByClassName("lan_Ans").style.display = "none";. Now none of the fields hides.

Comment: It makes life simpler for others if you provide the generated mark up rather than the server code that generates it. Also, rather than toggling between "table-cell" and "none", it's much simpler to toggle between "" (empty string) and "none", that way the element goes to it's default or inherited style (which might be anything). That also allows a hide/show function to be generic and can be applied to any element, regardless of its default *style.display* value.

Comment: *getElementsByClassName* returns a NodeList. You have to iterate over it to hide each node. Or you can change the style rule instead, which is very much faster for lots of elements.

Comment: Oh thanks RobG. I can't understand. Can you give the brief explanation about toggle (none ,empty string and table-cell).

Comment: Now what I have to change in my coding. @RobG

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

Your PHP code

```
function populateSystemAsset_byLocation($locations,$asset_types,$employees,$check)
 {
  echo "<tr class='toggleClass'>";

// Code for td 

echo "</tr>";
}//function
```

Now change `JS` function like this

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  var flag = 0;

  function hide()
   {
    if(flag == 0)
    {
    document.getElementById("viewbutton").value = "View Less";
    document.getElementsByClassName("toggleClass").style.display = "table-cell";
    flag = 1;
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById("viewbutton").value = "View More";
    document.getElementsByClassName("toggleClass").style.display = "none";
    flag = 0;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ya thanks sunil. But I wont need to hide entire Row. I have to hide only part of the columns from echo Row. Contently first two columns should be display. Only hides / shows, remaining columns  depends on user click the button.

Comment: @SanKaRan Then please provide HTML table also

Comment: @suil. I did not write any specific code in html. That function itself print all the elements. Check out above PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, change the *id* to *class* then use something like the following to toggle the display:

```js
    // Default value for flag
    var flag = true;

    function showHide() {

      // Toggle button label
      document.getElementById("viewbutton").value = flag? 'View more' : 'View less';

      // Toggle display of rows
      var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.remarks, lan, .wifi, .scrapped, .remarks_Ans, .lan_Ans, .wifi_Ans, scrapped_Ans');

      for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        nodes[i].style.display = flag? 'none' : '';
      }

      // Toggle the flag true/false
      flag = !flag;
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="showHide()" id="viewbutton" value="Show less">
<table>
  <tr class="remarks"><td>remarks</td></tr>
  <tr class="wifi"><td>wifi</td></tr>
</table>
```

Note that this can also be achieved by adding or removing a class that has *display:none* as a rule (which is a much better option).